# Migrating code from a PIC18F2480 to a PIC18F2680 Microcontroller

Tags: c, microcontroller, pic, mplab

I have bootloader code written in MPLAB for an 18F2480 processor.  My current project requires me to upgrade the microcontroller to an 18F2680.

(The main difference between the two chips is that the 2480 has 16K of program memory/768B RAM/ 256B EEPROM while the 2680 chip has 64K of program memory/3K of RAM and 1K of EEPROM.)

I have changed the selected device to "PIC18f2680" as well as replaced the 2480 header file for the 18f2680.h file.  I am having complications communicating with the 2680 using the program I normally use to update the 2480 firmware. 
(I cannot provide details on this software as it is propietary.)

I just wanted to know if there are any known issues/complications that come with migrating code from a 2480 to a 2680.

And FWIW, I have successfully replaced the 2480 with a 2580 which has 32K of program memory, 1536 RAM bytes, and 256B of EEPROM.  The code works fine and all I had to do was replace the header file and choose a different device in MPLAB.  Could it have to do with the different size of EEPROM for the 24/2580 and the 2680?

Comment: The problem you are having is proprietary.  Why do you ask here?  Ask the owner, pick up the phone.

Comment: @Hans - By proprietary I think he means it is code for which the rights belong to a client of his, but it's his problem to solve.  I think the question is totally legit and that someone maybe hasn't had enough caffeine today :)

Answer (score 2):

The PIC 18f2480 has a programming block of 32 bytes ( Datasheet Chapter 7.5 ).
The PIC 18F2680 has a programming block of 64 bytes ( Datasheet Chapter 6.5 ).

So the boot loader needs to be changed to use a different block size.